# What is the best way to implement polynomials with fractional exponents with SageMath?

Tags: sage

I want to perform manipulations in a polynomial ring where the terms can have fractional exponents. However just trying to use the fractions returns a value error. Obviously I could just set the indeterminate to be some power of itself to eliminate the fractional exponents, but this would involve altering all the formulas, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

### Puiseux series and Puiseux polynomials in SageMath

There are two Sage tickets on the topic, one about Puiseux series
and a later one about Puiseux polynomials.

- [Sage Trac ticket 9289: Implement Puiseux polynomials](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/9289)
- [Sage Trac ticket 4618: Puiseux series](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/4618)

There have also been numerous discussions on sage-devel and sage-support.

- [sage-devel discussions mentioning Puiseux](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sage-devel/puiseux%7Csort:date)
- [sage-support discussions mentioning Puiseux](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sage-support/puiseux%7Csort:date)

There is a package where this functionality is implemented.

- [**abelfunctions**: Abelian functions, Riemann surfaces, and algebraic curves](https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions)

  > A library for computing with Abelian functions, Riemann surfaces,
  > and algebraic curves.
  >
  > Documentation:
  > https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions/blob/master/doc/README.md

### Puiseux series and Puiseux polynomials in Oscar

If using Sage is not a strong requirement, you could have a look at
the implementation in [Oscar](https://oscar.computeralgebra.de/).
See the recent post on the Oscar blog:

- [Puiseux series: a challenging computation](https://oscar.computeralgebra.de/blogs/2018/08/03/PuiseuxSeries/)

Comment: Ha, I was going to answer regarding all this but didn't see you had answered it - nice.